# How can I view the AntiVirus Status on my Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, console, antivirus

Currently I have a bit of code that works in console but I was hoping I could avoid reinventing the wheel for something that should probably be super simple. Essentially I want to check for AV through WMI and display the AV status in a textbox.

```
 // Below checks windows 7,8,10 for the detected AntiVirus
    public static bool AntivirusInstalled()
    {
        string wmipathstr = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\SecurityCenter2";
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmipathstr, "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
            ManagementObjectCollection instances = searcher.Get();
            return instances.Count > 0;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool returnCode1 = AntivirusInstalled();
        Console.WriteLine("Antivirus Installed " + returnCode1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Read();
        textBox6.Text = "Antivirus Installed " + returnCode1.ToString();

    }

    public void OSViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    textBox6.Text = "Antivirus Installed " + AntivirusInstalled2.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Results of what? You haven't really made it clear what you are trying to do, or why what you did doesn't work.

Comment: If it is a console application what is `textBox6.Text` and if it is a windows forms application what are that `Console.WriteLine`s? What is `Main` and `Main2`?

Comment: @RonBeyer Im sorry, essentially the console lines above check WMI for the status of antivirus. I want to display said results in a textbox. This is a windows form application. I am not so great with C# so please bare with me.

Comment: This can't be a valid windows forms application, there is no point at which you start a form and `Console.Read`/`Console.Write` does not do anything in a winforms application. Its also not a valid console application because `Main` methods have to be static, and you can't access random textboxes inside of it. Please post the entire class.

Comment: I changed my question to better explain what I need/ what I'm working with.

Comment: @JoePearson Let me know if you have any question about the answer

Comment: @RezaAghaei I get an error that pops up "The method or operation is not implemented." then does nothing.

Comment: Probably you made a mistake somewhere and throwing a `NotImplementedException()`, It works properly here. Search for `NotImplementedException` in your project

Comment: the search doesnt bring anything up.

Comment: @JoePearson I shared a working [sample code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JQ9Sir) with you. Don't forget to add reference and you can paste content of sample in your `Program.cs` and run. Hope it help you to solve the problem:)

Comment: Im sure the answer is fine, I just cant seem to get it to work. I have that same error continually showing up.